# Does latest chrome support vp9 svc on webrtc environment?

Tags: webrtc, svc, vp9

I read an article(october, 2018) about simulcast, svc and codec.
Article says,

Right now, SVC is not supported by the current codecs in a WebRTC environment. It is being supported by VP9 (the successor to VP8) and H265 (the successor to H264). When codecs mature and WebRTC is able to support SVC it will be a big step forward. We're keeping our eyes peeled for when we can start using this. Until then, we will be using Simulcast.

Then, Does latest chrome browser not support vp9 svc on webrtc environment now?